# Play!Framework Compilation error

Tags: playframework

Sorry for my poor English.

I use command "play run appName" to start Play server and I get no errors.

But when I navigate to "localhost:9000", it shows a Compilation Error:

```
The file {module:docviewer}/app/controllers/PlayDocumentation.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The constructor File(File, String) is undefined
```

How can I resolve the error or disable the module:docvier?

I need your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you compile `PlayDocumentation.java` in a regular IDE?

Comment: 'c:\play-1.2.3\modules\docviewer\app\controllers>javac PlayDocumentation.java'

Comment: but i only get some errors about play framework like "play not found"

Comment: i create a new project with command "play new test_site",and i start the server ,no errors found..

Comment: it's a blank project or it has custom code?

Comment: It's ok after i restarted the server ;) Thanks~